# Excel VBA copy cells between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data between two workbooks: from cell A3 to the last cell in Voice to the corresponding cells in Voice_Files. I'm having trouble getting it to work, what am I doing worng? Below is the code:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim wB1 As Workbook
    Dim wB2 As Workbook
    Dim wS1 As Worksheet
    Dim wS2 As Worksheet
    Dim c1 As Range
    Dim c2 As Range


    Dim MASTER_FILE_NAME As String
    MASTER_FILE_NAME = "Voice.xlsm"
    Dim REPORT_FILE_NAME As String
    REPORT_FILE_NAME = "Voice_Files.xlsm"


    'Set wB1 = ThisWorkbook
    'Set wB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wB1 = Workbooks("Voice.xlsx")
    Set wB2 = Workbooks("Voice_Files.xlsx")

    Set wS1 = wB1.Sheets(1)
    Set wS2 = wB2.Sheets(1)


    'Take the whole column in master sheet
    Set c1 = wS1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)
    Set c2 = wS2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)

    'Transfer the values
    c2.Value = c1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `c1` and `c2` are each just one cell. `Debug.Print` their `.Address` and you'll see.

Comment: @BigBen yeah I know, I'm trying to select `cell` `A3` (plus all cells with data on its  right and below)in `c2` hence `Set c1 = wS1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)` which is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Maybe something more like: `Dim c1 As String`, then `c1 = "A2:" & wS1.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).Address` - you can then test if the range is correct by `wS1.Range(c1).Select`

Comment: @JustynaMK I tried it but it gives me error `Select Method of Range class failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose `Range`s within another `Range` call, i.e. 1st is the top left cell and 2nd is the bottom right.

```
With ws1
    Set c1 = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
End With
```